# Particular List item click to set bgcolor when l scroll down listview automatically another item list bgcolor set

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I create list view program and particular list item click to set backgroundcolor for list, when scroll down the list view automatically set color other item. please suggestion for my code.

sample code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvCountry;

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] country = { "India", "USA", "Russsia", "China", "Pakistan",
        "Canada", "UK", "arcot", "vellore", "gudiyattam", "arani",
        "palani", "chennai", "padi", "velacherry", "ambattur",
        "ambatttur ot", "maduravoyal", "guindy" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvCountry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);
    lvCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    // list selection part
    lvCountry.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // color selection select item
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Its better to use custom adapter to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ListView lvCountry;
int selectedPosition = -1;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] country = { "India", "USA", "Russsia", "China", "Pakistan",
        "Canada", "UK", "arcot", "vellore", "gudiyattam", "arani",
        "palani", "chennai", "padi", "velacherry", "ambattur",
        "ambatttur ot", "maduravoyal", "guindy" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvCountry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
if(position != selectedPosition)
       lvCountry.setBackgroundColor(null);
    // Array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);
    lvCountry.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    // list selection part
    lvCountry.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // color selection select item
    selectedPosition = position;
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    });
}}
```